# Combine a variable with SELECT results into an INSERT statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

> Users - uID (INT AUTO_INCREMENT), name (VARCHAR)
>
> Movies - mID (IN AUTO_INCREMENT), title (VARCHAR)
>
> Watched - uID (INT), mID (INT)

I'm writing a php function that constructs a query which adds records of movies watched by a particular person. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
function set_watched($name, $movies){
    $sql = "SET @userid = (SELECT uID FROM users WHERE name = '$name' LIMIT 1); ";
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO watched (uID, mID) VALUES ('";

    foreach ($movies as $index => $movie){

    }

}
```

**My question:**
Is there a way to combine the @userid variable with the results of a `SELECT mID FROM MOVIES WHERE title = $movie OR title = $movie [generated with foreach]`?

I don't want to generate separate SELECT statements for every movie title. Perhaps I don't even have to use the @userid variable at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO watched (uID, mID)
  SELECT User.uID, Movies.mID
  FROM (SELECT uID FROM Users WHERE Users.name = '$name' LIMIT 1) AS User, Movies      
  WHERE ";

foreach ($movies as $index => $movie){
  $sql .= "Movies.title = '$movie' OR ";
}

$sql = substr($sql, 0, -4) . ";";
```

Comment: That _almost_ works. I'm getting the "Every derived table must have its own alias" error. All I need to do is to figure out where to add AS clauses

Comment: Thank you so much! I used this instead of substr :  if ($index < count($movies) - 1){
   $sql .= " OR ";
  }

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using arrays and imploding them for this sort of an application. Also, I wouldn't try and force these two things into one query. I would either:

1. Modify the function parameters to accept `uID` as its input, instead of `name`
2. Change the logic to two queries.

Besides, PHP's [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function doesn't support multiple queries, so if you're using the standard mysql functions, you can't execute two queries with one call to mysql_query.

Running with case #2, you can use something like this (untested, of course):

```
$sql = 'SELECT uID FROM users WHERE name = "' . $name. '" LIMIT 1';
$result = mysql_query( $sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row( $result);
mysql_free_result( $result);

$values_array = array();
foreach ($movies as $index => $movie)
{
     $values_array[] = '( "' . $row['uID'] . '", "' . $movie . '")';
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO watched (uID, mID) VALUES ' . implode( ', ', $values_array);
$result = mysql_query( $sql);
```

Comment: I'm using mysqli. I would really love to combine all of it into one query, which I know is possible.

Comment: This solution does combine everything in one insert statement. It makes use of the fact that MySQL allows specifying multiple lists of values in an insert statement. However, it does run a separate select to get the data. In itself that's not a problem, but this also means that all data is sent from MySQL to PHP and then back to MySQL again, while in Karsten's answer, the data never leaves the MySQL database. So while it's good to know this syntax, it's not the best solution by far.